# How to do increment in map function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

```
`{Array.apply(null, {length:this.state.length}).map((value, i) => ( 
<div>
<div>{i}</div>
<div>{i+1}</div>
<div>{i+2}</div>
</div>)}
<button onClick={()=>this.loadmore(event)}>Load More</button>`
```

Below is the load more code

```
public loadmore(e)
{
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState(prevState => ({length:prevState.length+1}))
}
```

I want to display 
012 (when i click load more 456 should appear)
345
678

Instead I'm getting 
012
123
234

Is there any way to increment the value of i after i+2

Comment: Where is your `loadmore()`?

Comment: what does your loadmore() do? You are using the index of the array to display a value. I don't even see how you show 234 on the second approach? As in your current example your array has always 3 items and therefore the index will always be 0, 1 and 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your callback, `i` is the index of the entry (`0` for the first entry, `1` for the second, etc.), so if you're outputting three items per entry and you want to start counting from 1, the three items will be `i * 3 + 1`, `i * 3 + 2`, and `i * 3 + 3`:

```
Array.from({length: this.state.length}).map((value, i) => {
    i *= 3;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{i + 1}</div>
            <div>{i + 2}</div>
            <div>{i + 3}</div>
        </div>
    );
})
```

(Or each div could be `<div>{++i}</div>`.)

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {length: 1};
        this.loadmore = this.loadmore.bind(this);
    }
    
    loadmore() {
        this.setState(({length}) => ({length: length + 1}));
    }
    
    render() {
        const {length} = this.state;
        const divs = Array.from({length: this.state.length}).map((value, i) => {
            i *= 3;
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>{i + 1}</div>
                    <div>{i + 2}</div>
                    <div>{i + 3}</div>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {divs}
                <input type="button" onClick={this.loadmore} value="Load More" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I changed a couple of other things in the live example:

- You can use destructuring to make your `setState` call a bit more concise if you like:

  ```
  this.setState(({length}) => ({length: length + 1}));
  ```
- I bound `loadmore` in the constructor rather than recreating a function on every render in `onClick`.
- You had a typo in your JSX, missing `/` on the closing `</div>` tags